# How to debug an "unresolved externals" error when trying to compile assembly?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, linker-errors, masm

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and am attempting to write "raw" assembly. I'm just starting to learn assembly so I don't know too much about it but I'd like to write assembly if possible without wrapping it in C/C++ or any other languages.

I have a file main.asm with the following code that I am trying to get running. I am just looking to confirm that I can get an asm program running so that I can play with the code as I read how assembly works.

```
.MODEL FLAT
.code
    neg eax
    add eax,5 ;eax = eax -5
END
```

When compiling, I am getting the following errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _main 
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

How can I resolve this and get an understanding of what is occurring?

Comment: Note that even if your code would link, it would most like crash after reaching the `add eax,5` because you didn't add code to shut down the process.  The CPU doesn't know that your program ends there and continues executing whatever is in RAM after that.

Comment: If you don't need the _C_ runtime then after `.code` add a label `_main:` . After `add eax,5` add a `ret` and then change `END` to `END _main`

Answer (score 0):

The CRT startup code wants to call a function called `main` (or `_main` in asm).  You didn't provide one, so your program doesn't link.

Exactly the same error as if you compiled a C program that was missing a `main` function.  Go look for some examples of MASM-syntax hello world, or of declaring a function.  For example, [How to write hello world in assembler under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembler-under-windows#1032422) has a MASM answer (the question is tagged NASM, so most of the answers are for NASM, the other major flavour of intel-syntax assembly.)

Other hits on SO include [x86 masm hello world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902697/x86-masm-hello-world), which manually calls the CRT init functions from a static executable, so that's more complex than you need if you're just writing the equivalent of a simple C program.

---

**And/or look at compiler-generated asm output to see how it does it**, with `PROC` / `END`.  http://godbolt.org/ has MSVC installed, as well as gcc / clang (which emit GAS syntax)